# What is exactly fully convolutional layer?

Tags: deep-learning, convolution

What is exactly fully convolutaionl layer? I mean, why is it '**fully**'? The wording in [[Long]](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jonlong/long_shelhamer_fcn.pdf) is quite confusing to me.

Is it because they never use fully connected layer? **Or** is it because the convolution layers obtained by the 'convolutionization' described in Figure 2 have their kernels cover their entire input regions?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not (directly) about programming, but about terminology in Machine Learning. This might be on-topic on http://ai.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @MSalters Thank you for the feedback. But few guys already answered it.   I cannot delete it, can I?

Comment: It is not fully convolutional layer, its a fully convolutional *network*.

Answer (score 2):

Do you see the last part in this image " fully connected" in fully convolution network we remove this part. But then how can do classification since we already have many channels with big activation map ?

In the example you mentioned they do up-sampling and their cost function is to measure the error between the re-construed image (up-sampled) and the ground truth.

So why it is called fully convolution because it is just convolution there. spatial feature extraction.

[image: CNN]

Answer (score 0):

The phrase comes from a blend of the phrases "fully connected layer" with "convolutional layer". You can think of it as a fully connected layer which acts on a sub-region of an image. Then, instead of getting a single output feature vector for the whole image, you get a set of vectors, each per its corresponding image part. Where the vectors are formed to produce a map, which is a reminiscent of convolutional feature maps.